# Istio skip Oauth JWT when calling from within mesh

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, istio

I have 2 APIs, say A and B. **Both are within mesh but different namespaces**. Now using Istio, and OAuth I have setup A,B such that any user is redirected to SSO before accessing them. However when A calls B, it is also getting redirected to SSO IdP. I want to allow calls within mesh between A->B without Authentication. How can I do so?

Comment: Something similar to this https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/42162#issue-1464443434